# Is it possible to select all connected or unconnected nodes?

Tags: interface, shortcut, node-editor, selection-tools

Is it possible to select all connected or unconnected nodes in the node editor with a keyboard shortcut or operation?
(I thought maybe <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> like in Edit mode, but apparently not)

Am I just missing something?
Or is there no way to do this without doing it manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use *Select Linked To* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and *Select Linked From* <kbd>L</kbd> repeatedly till you have all connected nodes selected. Then you can Inverse selection <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to select the unlinked nodes.

Alternatively you can use the following script that will add a *Select > Select Linked* menu option.

```
from itertools import chain
import bpy

def get_linked(node, processed=None):
    if processed is None:
        processed = []
    processed.append(node)
    for socket in chain(node.inputs, node.outputs):
        for link in socket.links:
            target = link.from_node if node == link.to_node else link.to_node
            if target not in processed:
                get_linked(target, processed)
    return processed

class NODE_OT_SelectLinked(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_description="Select all nodes linked to the active node"
    bl_idname = "node.select_linked"
    bl_label = "Select Linked Nodes"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_node

    def execute(self, context):
        for node in get_linked(context.active_node):
            node.select = True
        return {"FINISHED"}

def menu(self, context):
    self.layout.operator("node.select_linked", text="Select Linked")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(NODE_OT_SelectLinked)
    bpy.types.NODE_MT_select.append(menu)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NODE_OT_SelectLinked)
    bpy.types.NODE_MT_select.remove(menu)

register()
```

*To auto load: save the above in [scripts/startup/](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Introduction/Installing_Blender/DirectoryLayout) with a .py file extension.*